# Как использовать свою переменую в array_filter

Tags: php

есть переменая `$uGoods` мне её нужно использовать  в array_filter типа такого

```
$color  = array_filter($uGoods->goods->addfeilds, function($item,$uGoods) {
    return $item->id == $uGoods->color;
});
```

но так не возможно по документации а как можно так

```
function addColor($item,$uGoods)
     {
             return $item->id == $uGoods->color;
     }                                       var_dump(array_filter($uGoods->gods->addfeilds, 'addColor'));
```

тоже не вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так :

```
$color  = array_filter($uGoods->goods->addfeilds, function($item)use($uGoods) {
    return $item->id == $uGoods->color;
});
```